# Remove the root when serializing/deserializing XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm using the `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` classes along with the `XmlSerializer` class to serialize and deserialize some XML models. Sadly, the format of the XML is out of my hands, and one of the files expects an invalid format, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<some_element>...</some_element>
<some_element>...</some_element>
<some_element>...</some_element>
```

Basically, it doesn't have a singleton root node. Can I make the serializer somehow read and reproduce such a format?

Note: I'd like to stick to the standard interface (`IXmlSerializable`), so I don't have to differentiate between this and other models.

Edit:

I've tried to implement `IXmlSerializable` explicitly for the type:

```
public class TheInvalidModel : IXmlSerializable
{
    [XmlElement("some_element")]
    public List<SomeElement> Elements { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        // TODO
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeElement));
        foreach (var e in Elements)
        {
            ser .Serialize(writer, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly, this automatically writes out a root element.

Edit 2:

With this sample:

```
var model = new TheInvalidModel
{
    Elements = new List<SomeElement>
    {
        new SomeElement { },
        new SomeElement { },
        new SomeElement { },
    }
};
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TheInvalidModel));
var tw = new StringWriter();
serializer.Serialize(tw, model);
Console.WriteLine(tw.ToString());
```

I get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<TheInvalidModel>
  <SomeElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
  <SomeElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
  <SomeElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
</TheInvalidModel>
```

But what I'd need instead is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<SomeElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
<SomeElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
<SomeElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

Comment: Please, share the code which you've tried

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Added

Comment: @PeterLenkefi also add some sample output of the code you tried if you could.

Comment: @sommmen Also added

Comment: When you do not have a well formed xml file (more than one node at root) easiest way of parsing is to add a root : string xml = "<Root>" + xml_file_string + "</Root>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write non-conformant xml code with a more manual approach;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.conformancelevel?view=netcore-3.1

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
settings.CloseOutput = false;

// Create the XmlWriter object and write some content.
MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(strm, settings);
writer.WriteElementString("orderID", "1-456-ab");
writer.WriteElementString("orderID", "2-36-00a");
writer.Flush();
writer.Close();

// Do additional processing on the stream.
```

With this you could loop your SomeElements list and output the xml.

Comment: I guess this means I can say goodbye to `IXmlSerializable` as this now requires a custom handling? That change would ripple through basically everything.

Comment: @PeterLenkefi well i tried doing this inside WriteToXml like your question - but that generates a root tag for the model regardless of what you do. So yeah - something like this is the only thing i could come up with. Maybe you could still apply the correct normal writer and do some post processing instead? so you'd still use IXmlSerializable you serialize the thing and then just before you're writing to file (or you edit the file afterwards) you manipulate the data? maybe not the prettiest but then you don't have to alter your current approach.

Comment: Keep in mind you're writing invalid xml anyways so you're gonna need to do something weird at some point anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(File.ReadAllText(INPUT_FILENAME));
            StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(builder);
            //fill string writer with existing code
            //I just used input file for testing
            XElement model = XElement.Parse(tw.ToString());

            string ident = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>";

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(OUTPUT_FILENAME);
            writer.WriteLine(ident);
            foreach(XElement someElement in model.Descendants("SomeElement"))
            {
                 writer.WriteLine(someElement);
            }
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, both answers were useful to me, I just had to accept one. Thank you anyway!